# How to dynamically reload GUI in eclipse kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I am building GUI in eclipse kepler and to reload changes on classes I need every time to terminate VM and start it again by Ctrl+F11.

Maybe there is a way to reload classes dynamically in eclipse. Something like jrebel but on desktop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a recent JRE, Eclipse will do so called "hot code replacement" and modify the class files on the fly. That works only for certain kinds of changes. It's also explained in the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F) (but at the time of writing the page was not accessible).

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have simply installed JRebel and it works - it reloads classes and I am glad.